# How do I validate a JWT using JwtSecurityTokenHandler and a JWKS endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am prototyping the use of IdentityServer4 to secure several services, with the caveat that those services will likely not be migrated (in the forseeable future) to use the OWIN middleware idiom of ASP.NET Core.  Consequently, I can not leverage the many middleware helpers that automate the validation of a JWT by simply providing the well-known JWKS endpoint of IdentityServer, among other things.

It would be nice if I could reconstruct this behavior, and I'd like to leverage Microsoft's [`JwtSecurityTokenHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.aspx) implementation if possible.  However, I can not figure out how to utilize the `JsonWebKeySet` and `JsonWebKey` types provided via IdentityServer's discovery endpoint to extract keys and perform the validation.

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler` uses [`TokenValidationParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.aspx) to validate a JWT, and those parameters require an instance of one or more [`SecurityKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytoken.aspx) objects to perform the validation.

```
ClaimsPrincipal ValidateJwt(string token, IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryResponse discovery)
{
    JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

    TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        ValidIssuer = "expected-issuer",
        ValidAudience = "expected-audience",
        IssuerSigningKeys = discovery.KeySet.Keys /* not quite */
    };

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    return handler.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
}
```

How do I perform the necessary translation from `JsonWebKeySet` to `IEnumerable<SecurityKey>` so that the validation can occur?  Is there another method (apart from OWIN middleware) that will also work using the `DiscoveryResponse` data above?

(Sadly, the documentation for `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` is not up to date.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check this sample:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/old/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L148

It manually retrieves the key from the JWK and populates the validation parameters.

Comment: This is fantastic -- thank you!  I overlooked the samples and was getting lost in navigating the source code of middleware implementations :)

Comment: Any implementation without Identity Server?

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. This does though: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Clients/old/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs

Comment: But how can I add such custom validation login not in controller but in some proper place? Can you please provide more production like solution?

Answer (score 10):

```
var jwks = "{ keys: [..." // your jwks json string
var signingKeys = new JsonWebKeySet(jwks).GetSigningKeys();
```

Then simply assign it to the `IssuerSigningKeys` property of your `TokenValidationParameters`.

If you are reading the jwks from a web service, then you would need a http client to read it first.

Comment: Worked perfectly! So much simpler.

Comment: How to get jwks json?

Answer (score 0):

Using code from the packages:

- `IdentityModel`
- `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

Imports:

```ml
open IdentityModel
open IdentityModel.Client
open System.Security.Cryptography
open System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
```

Conversion from `JsonWebKey` to `SecurityKey`:

```ml
module JsonWebKey =

  let toSecurityKey (webKey : Jwk.JsonWebKey) =
    let e = Base64Url.Decode(webKey.E)
    let n = Base64Url.Decode(webKey.N)

    let mutable rsap = RSAParameters()

    rsap.Exponent <- e
    rsap.Modulus <- n

    let key = RsaSecurityKey(rsap)

    key.KeyId <- webKey.Kid

    key :> SecurityKey
```

Then to validate a token:

```ml
task {
  let cache = new DiscoveryCache(oidConfigUrl)

  let! ddr = cache.GetAsync()

  let tokenHandler = JwtSecurityTokenHandler()

  let validationParameters = TokenValidationParameters()

  let issuerSigningKeys =
    ddr.KeySet.Keys
    |> Seq.map JsonWebKey.toSecurityKey
    |> Seq.toList

  validationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys <- issuerSigningKeys
  validationParameters.ValidIssuer <- ddr.Issuer
  validationParameters.ValidAudience <- "account"
  validationParameters.RequireSignedTokens <- true
  validationParameters.ValidateIssuer <- true
  validationParameters.ValidateLifetime <- true
  validationParameters.ValidateAudience <- true

  let! validationResult = 
    tokenHandler.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken, validationParameters)

  printfn $"IsValid: {validationResult.IsValid}"
  printfn $"Exception: {validationResult.Exception}"
  printfn $"Claims: {validationResult.Claims |> Seq.toList}"
  printfn $"ClaimsIdentity: {validationResult.ClaimsIdentity.ToString()}"
}
```