# How to validate JWT Token using JWKS in Dot Net Core

Tags: validation, authentication, jwt, token, jwk

In C#, I need to validate the Bearer Token against the JWKS (Json object which represent the set of keys like below)

```
{ 
   "keys":[ 
      { 
         "e":"AQAB",
         "kid":"unique key",
         "kty":"RSA",
         "n":"some value"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do this using Microsoft's Nuget packages `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

Use following code to create token validator:

```cs
private static bool ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    try
    {
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
        return validatedToken != null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for usage you have to load JWKS and select a key for validation parameters:

```cs
var jwksJson = @"
    { 
       ""keys"":[ 
          { 
             ""e"":""AQAB"",
             ""kid"":""unique key"",
             ""kty"":""RSA"",
             ""n"":""some value""
          }
       ]
    }";

var token = "eyJhb...";
var jwks = new JsonWebKeySet(jwksJson);
var jwk = jwks.Keys.First();

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    IssuerSigningKey = jwk,
    ValidAudience = "", // Your API Audience, can be disabled via ValidateAudience = false
    ValidIssuer = ""  // Your token issuer, can be disabled via ValidateIssuer = false
};

var isValid = ValidateToken(token, validationParameters);
```

Comment: What if you don't want to use the first key - what if you want to check if any of them are matching by kid?

Comment: @th3morg You could create multiple `TokenValidationParameters` and validate each of them or you could select `JsonWebKey` by `KeyId` property.

Comment: Just for anyone else with the same question as @th3morg - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64274938/419934 which shows you how to get the key list into the correct format which can then be used to set the IssuerSigningKeys in the TokenValidationParameters field.