# automatic download JWKS asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I am new to JSON Web Key Sets. I would like to automatic download JWKS for JWT token validation.

I did google but not find any example using .net core webapi 6.O

Comment: Does my answer useful to u ?

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [this thread that we need to download the `.well-known` file every time](https://community.auth0.com/t/validating-jwt-with-jwks-can-we-store-jwks-file-instead-of-downloading-every-time/24181/2) we validate the jwt token. I excerpted the content of the answer and put it below to prevent the link from being invalid and inaccessible.

> Please do cache the result of the .well-known file. It will change, though extremely rarely.
> Your code must handle when the key used to sign the token does not appear in your cache, then you will have to re-download the file.
> John

We can download the jwks file when verifying the jwt token. [In .net core, we can use HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0). And we can download jwks via the url like below

```
https://your_domain/.well-known/jwks.json
```

The most important thing is we need to use Microsoft's Nuget packages `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.

And we can use HttpClient to download the jwks file, then read it and convert to string format. Then we can use JwtSecurityTokenHandler to Validate Token. Like below:

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
try
{
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
    return validatedToken != null;
}
```

**If you want more code details, you can refer to this post.**

[How to validate JWT Token using JWKS in Dot Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60234510/7687666)